# Redstone particles don't change their color

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, packets

I'm trying to send colored redstone particles to player via packets using ProtocolLib. I Googled that to make them colored, I need use the `offset` parameters as the RGB system. However, it didn't work as intended; particles are still red or have random color (see below), and `offset` still is used as randomizer of each particle from the given location.
My code:

```
PacketContainer packet = new PacketContainer(PacketType.Play.Server.WORLD_PARTICLES);
packet.getModifier().writeDefaults();
packet.getParticles().write(0, Particle.REDSTONE);
float x = (float) loc.getX();
float y = (float) loc.getY() + 3;
float z = (float) loc.getZ();
float red = 0;
float green = 0;
float blue = 1;
packet.getFloat().write(0, x).write(1, y).write(2, z); // Location
packet.getFloat().write(3, red).write(4, green).write(5, blue); // Offset
packet.getFloat().write(6, 0F); // Particle data ?
packet.getIntegers().write(0, 1); // Amount

ProtocolManager manager = ProtocolLibrary.getProtocolManager();
try {
    for (Player player : getters) manager.sendServerPacket(player, packet);
} catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

I tried to change `amount` and particle `data`. If particle `data` is `0`, then particles are red, in other cases up to `1` particles are random colored.
I'm using ProtocolLib 4.3.0 and Spigot 1.12.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem, to spawn colored true redstone particle there must be 3 things:

1. `Amount` must be `0`
2. `Data` must be `1`
3. Red component (x offset) must be `x - 1` (because this component automatically increased by 1 before pushing into the packet)